# How to apply scipy filter in Polars DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, scipy, python-polars

I'm currently using savgol filter in my DataFrame, which has 3 columns x, y, z With float values of a signal from a micro controller

in pandas it's straight forward

```
df["x"] = savgol_filter(df["x"], 51, 1)
df["y"] = savgol_filter(df["y"], 51, 1)
df["z"] = savgol_filter(df["z"], 51, 1)
```

how to implement the same in polar df

I tried using this method

```
df.with_columns([
        (savgol_filter(df["x"], 51, 1)).alias("x"),
        (savgol_filter(df["y"], 51, 1)).alias("x"),
        (savgol_filter(df["z"], 51, 1)).alias("x"),
])
```

The above code returns Attribute error.
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'alias'

Edit:
My question is fairly simple, what is the right syntax/method to implement a scipy filters in polars DataFrame?.

Comment: Saying "... which doesn't seem to work" does not provide enough information to be useful and needs more explanation.  Do you get an error?  If so, show the complete error message.  If there is no error, but the result is not what you expected, provide an example that shows what you got and what you expected.  It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a general way in polars to use custom functions in polars depending if you want to use them on a single element (`apply`) or on a whole series (`map`). In your case it would be the whole series. For a more detail explanation of both option you can check out the user guide [here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/custom_functions.html)

So depending if you want to change the whole DataFrame or keep the original columns here are the to solutions:

## Data

```
import polars as pl
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
import numpy as np

n = 100
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": np.random.randint(0, 100, n),
        "y": np.random.randint(0, 100, n),
        "z": np.random.randint(0, 100, n),
    }
)
```

## Solution 1

```
df.select(pl.all().map(lambda x: savgol_filter(x.to_numpy(), 51, 1)).explode())
```

## Solution 2

```
df.with_columns(
    [
        pl.all()
        .map(lambda x: savgol_filter(x.to_numpy(), 51, 1))
        .explode()
        .suffix("_savgol")
    ]
)
```

If you don't want to apply the function on all columns you can replace `pl.all()` with for example `pl.col("x")`

Comment: The link is now broken, I guess [this is the new page](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/user-defined-functions/)